# Keras LSTM: how to handle sequence tagging for sentence boundary detection (NLP)?

Tags: python, keras, nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to build a sentence boundary detection model for texts using Keras LSTMs. The goal is that I can give the model a text in the form of a list of word-tokens and then I get a list of labels representing each token in the input.
I have the following training data: 6 texts of different lengths, each of these texts are annotated at word level with one of the following labels: ["B-SEN", "E-SEN", "O"].
Example data:

```
X = [
["This", "is", "text", "one", ".", ...],
["This", "is", "text", "two", ".", ...],
...
["This", "is", "text", "six", ".", ...]]

y = [
["B-SEN", "O", "O", "O", "E-SEN", ...],
["B-SEN", "O", "O", "O", "E-SEN", ...],
...
["B-SEN", "O", "O", "O", "E-SEN", ...]]
```

My training data X I have now converted that each token/word is converted to a feature vector of 8 features. y I have also encoded starting at 1 for B-SEN. Since the texts have different lengths I have padded the training data based on the longest of my samples. The longest sample/text of these 6 texts is 80451 tokens long. The shorter texts were padded with 0-vectors in X representing the padding and the y arrays with 0 entries.

Since I am completely new to this topic, I wanted to start with a simple model consisting of one LSTM layer and then extend it later on.
Now I have the question of how to model this problem/approach best?
The most trivial approach in my opinion would be to say I choose my `input_shape = (6, 80451, 8)`

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(6, 80451, 8), return_sequences=True))
```

That would mean that I would look at a whole sample at one timestep, right? Does this make sense for this problem? Most sentences have a length of < 100 tokens. For example, if I wanted my model to look at only 100 tokens per timestep per sample, how could I do that, would I have to restructure my training data?